# I am trying to create function in sdf file and getting error : there was an error parsing the query token in error function

Tags: database, function, sdf

I am creating an .sdf file in to my local computer and creating tables and functions from .txt file.
I am done with tables but when i try to create function i am getting error :

**There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = FUNCTION ]**

And here is my code;

```
StreamReader stF = new StreamReader(@"QUERY\\CreateTables.txt");
                SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand(stF.ToString(), conn);
                string lineF = "";
                while ((lineF = stF.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                   
                    cm.CommandText = lineF.ToString();
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cm.CommandText = "";

                }

                stF = new StreamReader(@"QUERY\\CreateFunctions.txt");
                cm = new SqlCeCommand(stF.ToString(), conn);
                lineF = "";
                while ((lineF = stF.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    cm.CommandText = lineF.ToString();
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cm.CommandText = "";

                }
    

And here is my function in txt file;
(Function is only one line in txt)

CREATE FUNCTION [GET_BOLGE_ADI]
(
@sezon_ BIGINT,
@fabrika_id_ NCHAR(20),
@bolge_id_ NCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS NCHAR(150)
AS 
begin 
declare 
@bolge_adi_ NCHAR(150) 
set @bolge_adi_=(select BOLGE_ADI from CFTC_BOLGE where SEZON=@sezon_ and upper(FABRIKA_ID)=@fabrika_id_ and upper(BOLGE_ID)=@bolge_id_) return (@bolge_adi_)
end;
GO
```